# Winforms : can't we write code in Main() instead of having to use threads (like backgroundWorker, etc...)?

Tags: c#, winforms

Discovering Winforms, I was wondering why code written in the `Main()`, after the function that launches the form (`Application.Run(new Form1());`), is never reached while Form is running ?

Does a Winform necessarily need threads (backgroundWorker, etc...) to execute functions outside of UI event handlers ? Why can't we simply write these functions in the `Main()`, instead of having to create threads ?

A Winform is "only" some event handlers, so why does it "block" the Main() ?

Thank you for your enlightenment !

Comment: This style of application has one UI thread which executes everything by default on that thread. Unless you create new threads (using BackgroundWorker, etc.), everything you do is on that UI thread. So any long-running call, such as processing large amounts of data, or connecting to a remote data source, will take processing time on the UI thread. This is why we create off-UI threads to do those things. `Why can't we simply write these functions in the Main()` well do you mean local lambdas to execute these things defined in `void Main()`? ...

Comment: That line of code `Application.Run(new Form1())` spawns the UI thread. And it blocks. This model gives the coder a UI thread, because it's supposed to be *easy* for Joe Coder to make a window. With advanced knowledge you can manipulate the UI thread as you see fit, i.e. launch your own UI thread and message loop by changing that code around. This model is just simple to use for the average person

Comment: @djv : Thank you for your answer. I don't know about "local lambdas", I meant : What if, independantly from UI elements, I want to write  `Console.WriteLine("Hello World")` (for example, but it could be much more complex) after the `Application.Run(new Form1()` in the `Main()` ? Why do I need another thread (or a backgroundWorker) to do that ?

Comment: @djv (about your second comment) : Oh OK, I get it. So where it is written that Application.Run(new Form1()) will be a blocking thread ? Is there any way to change this so I can write code in the Main() ?

More broadly speaking, would a WPF app be more appropriate in this case ?

Comment: `Application.Run()` enters the main message loop on the *current* thread. Once the form closes, the loop terminates, `Application.Run` returns, and execution resumes within `Main`.

Comment: When you write a windowed app (as opposed to a console app), and you start it from the command line, the app starts and the console prompt returns immediately (for an example, start `Notepad` from the console).  Writing to the console from inside such an app would make no sense.  If you want to use `WriteLine` calls for debugging, you can call `Debug.WriteLine` and the output will appear within the Visual Studio console.  But as @djv points out, you don't get to do that after the call to `Application.Run`.  I'm curious what you'd like to do in Main after the app starts running

Comment: @Flydog57 `Console.WriteLine(message)` prints to the VS Output window in a WinForms app. You can set a stream to consume these messages other than the Output window, a text file for example, even in WinForms

Comment: @FLydog57 : Indeed, it was just an example, I don't mean writing such thing. A button click on the form triggers a regular flow of data on a COM port. The UI needs to be updated according to that flow of data.

I understand that this can be done inside the Form using another thread or background worker, I simply don't understand why can't this be done in the Main().

Comment: @Elaws you can do things in Main, for example put `Application.Run` inside a `Try...Catch` to handle otherwise unhandled exceptions (for example you want to catch all those and display a crash messagebox, and email yourself etc.)

Comment: @Elaws because `Main` generally shouldn't know about what's going on inside the form.

Comment: You can certainly write an application without `Application.Run` which just does a bunch of things, if you don't want a UI, similar to a console app, and it will just run through all the commands, as long as they are not blocked, and the thread will exit and the application will end. `Application.Run` keeps the thread alive while the form is open. This is kind of the point

Comment: Something in `Main` has to block, otherwise, the program will continue past the `Application.Run` call, get to the end of `Main` and end the process.  You don't need to do things on other threads.  If the operations you want to do have an `async` API, you can call them from the main thread and work with them asynchronously.  The `async` and `await` features of C# make WinForms much easier to work with.

Comment: @Flydog57 That's not true.  You could design a version of `Main` that was asynchronous.  Microsoft didn't do that, but they certainly *could* do that if they wanted to.  The process doesn't end when `Main` ends, it ends when all foreground threads stop running.  The one running the `Main` method need not be the only one.

Comment: *Why can't we simply write these functions in the Main(), instead of having to create threads ?* - Main is a method. You could write local functions inside it but you wouldn't be able to call them from outside so there seems little point.. I find a reasonable amount of this question quite confused; I'd say the vast majority of winforms apps never create any new threads and do all their work with the one that also processes the message loop, but "writing code/functions/methods" in any part of the codebase and "creating threads" are two completely different things..

Answer (score 0):

`Application.Run()` starts a message pump to process the Windows API that displays forms on the screen and processes windows messages, executing the UI event handlers. You can think of this message pump as loop that never returns until the application is exited. Thus, code following `Application.Run()` will not execute until your main form is closed.

Comment: Thank you ! So, Winforms are completely designed with the philosophy that if user needs heavy treatment ( = outside of UI event handlers), it needs to be done in another thread in the Form.cs (backgroundWorker, etc...), and not in the Main() of the Program.cs, right ?

Comment: You could start background threads before calling `Application.Run()`, but otherwise, the answer is yes.

Comment: @Elaws: and be aware that if you do anything outside of the _UI Thread_ (the thread that runs the main window), that code can't directly do anything with the main window or anything associated with it.  Look up `Control.Invoke` and `Control.InvokeRequired` (remembering that `Form` derives from `Control`) for ways of marshalling a call from a background thread to the UI thread.

Comment: @Flydog57 : thanks ! I noticed that with some interthread errors when trying to access ui elements from a backgroundWorker ! However, you can access global variables declared in Form from a backgroundWorker or thread, right?

Comment: @Adam Thank you ! What would be the difference between a thread launched before Application.Run() and a thread (or backgroundWorker) launched in Form, in terms of how they would communicate with the UI thread ?

Comment: @Elaws: there is absolutely no difference in terms of actual processing, as both create/use the same background thread. In terms of best practices, it is usually better to keep the thread/backgroundworker/task creation within the context that it is related to. This helps when debugging.

Comment: @elaws: there are no _global variables_, anything globalish is generally a `static` member of a class. I expect that there are fewer restrictions on static members. However, cross thread access to nearly anything in a Forms app can do weird things. Example, put a breakpoint in code running on a background thread. Look at the `this` reference (i.e., the form). I've had VS hang while doing that

Comment: @Flydog57 OK, I managed to access a variable defined as `private int varName` in the beginning of a Form class (so no `static` keyword ) from a backgroundWorker, without any apparent problem.